# Bluetooth fails to connect to PoGo mobile printer or transfer files to it - Raspberry pi zero w

Tags: bluetooth

I am attempting a project where my Raspberry Pi Zero W (running Raspbian Stretch Lite) sends photo files to my Polaroid PoGo instant photo printer via Bluetooth, particularly the OBEX Object Push service which the PoGo uses.

I have installed the packages bluetooth and ussp-push, as bluez was already installed. Everything is up to date via apt-get upgrade.

I am able to pair with the device using the PIN code 6000 which all PoGo's share, but connections always fail. Ussp-push looks like it will establish a connection, but it hangs before doing so. I am at least somewhat confident this is not a hardware issue as when I was running with a desktop Blueman somehow managed to successfully send a file once, but my project requires CLI interaction only. I have attempted connecting to a better (2A) power supply, but this did not help.

Result of attempted connection via bluetoothctl:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo bluetoothctl
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...
[bluetooth]# 
[NEW] Controller B8:27:EB:15:E0:4E raspberrypi [default]
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# 
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
[bluetooth]# 
Discovery started
[bluetooth]# 
[CHG] Controller B8:27:EB:15:E0:4E Discovering: yes
[bluetooth]# 
[NEW] Device 00:04:48:15:B6:37 Polaroid 15 b6 37
[bluetooth]# agent on
[bluetooth]# 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# pairable on
[bluetooth]# 
Changing pairable on succeeded
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
[bluetooth]# 
Changing discoverable on succeeded
[bluetooth]# 
[CHG] Controller B8:27:EB:15:E0:4E Discoverable: yes
[bluetooth]# pair 00:04:48:15:B6:37 
Attempting to pair with 00:04:48:15:B6:37
[bluetooth]# 
Request PIN code
[bluetooth]# 
[agent] Enter PIN code: 6000
[bluetooth]# 
[CHG] Device 00:04:48:15:B6:37 Connected: yes
[Polaroid 15 b6 37]# 
[CHG] Device 00:04:48:15:B6:37 UUIDs: 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[Polaroid 15 b6 37]# 
[CHG] Device 00:04:48:15:B6:37 ServicesResolved: yes
[Polaroid 15 b6 37]# 
[CHG] Device 00:04:48:15:B6:37 Paired: yes
[Polaroid 15 b6 37]# 
Pairing successful
[Polaroid 15 b6 37]# 
[CHG] Device 00:04:48:15:B6:37 ServicesResolved: no
[Polaroid 15 b6 37]# 
[CHG] Device 00:04:48:15:B6:37 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# connect 00:04:48:15:B6:37 
Attempting to connect to 00:04:48:15:B6:37
[bluetooth]# 
[CHG] Device 00:04:48:15:B6:37 Connected: yes
[Polaroid 15 b6 37]# 
[CHG] Device 00:04:48:15:B6:37 ServicesResolved: yes
[Polaroid 15 b6 37]# 
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
[Polaroid 15 b6 37]# 
[CHG] Device 00:04:48:15:B6:37 ServicesResolved: no
[Polaroid 15 b6 37]# 
[CHG] Device 00:04:48:15:B6:37 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# quit
[bluetooth]# 
Agent unregistered
[bluetooth]# 
[DEL] Controller B8:27:EB:15:E0:4E raspberrypi [default]
[bluetooth]#
```

Result of attempted push via ussp-push:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ussp-push --debug 00:04:48:15:B6:37@1 /home/pi/uploads/image.jpg image.jpg
pushing file /home/pi/uploads/image.jpg
name=/home/pi/uploads/image.jpg, size=67159
__obex_connect: client_context_t = 0x1438aa8
Registered transport
Set user data
Created new objext
Started a new request
^C
```

I broke it there with ^C because it always just hangs at "Started a new request" no matter how long it is allowed to run.

Details of PoGo printer given by sdptool browse:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sdptool browse
Inquiring ...
Browsing 00:04:48:15:B6:37 ...
Service Name: OBEX Object Push
Service RecHandle: 0x10000
Service Class ID List:
  "OBEX Object Push" (0x1105)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 1
  "OBEX" (0x0008)
Language Base Attr List:
  code_ISO639: 0x656e
  encoding:    0x6a
  base_offset: 0x100
```

This problem is very troubling as I cannot seem to find a reason for why it is not working no matter how much searching I do. Any help would be appreciated. If any more data or logs are needed I would be happy to upload those.